# When does mutability of python class objects affect assignments?

Tags: python, class, object, mutable

My understanding of python's mutable feature for classes/objects is that if you make an assignment then any change to the original changes the assigned variable/object as well. I confused about this [piece of code below](https://codesays.com/2014/solution-to-flatten-binary-tree-to-linked-list-by-leetcode/).

```
# Recursive solution to Flatten Binary Tree to Linked List by LeetCode

# Definition for a  binary tree node
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution:
    # @param root, a tree node
    # @return root, a tree node
    def flattenHelper(self, root):
        if root == None:
            return None
        else:
            left = root.left
            right = root.right
            root.left = None    # Truncate the left subtree
            current = root

            # Flatten the left subtree
            current.right = self.flattenHelper(left)
            while current.right != None:    current = current.right

            # Flatten the right subtree
            current.right = self.flattenHelper(right)
            return root

    # @param root, a tree node
    # @return nothing, do it in place
    def flatten(self, root):
        self.flattenHelper(root)
        return
```

Question: How come the variable `left` does not automatically get set to `None` once `root.left = None` is executed?

Comment: root.left = None sets the name root.left to bind to None.  It doesn't change what left is bound to.  So the Node still exists, since something is referencing it.  it is just that root.left doesn't reference it anymore

Comment: @joelgoldstick Thank you, but I am still confused: if I do the following:
test=root,
root.left=TreeNode(5),
test.left.val will now be 5
why does the same thing not happen above?

Comment: @joelgoldstick I thought something similar to mutability of lists is happening here: if I have a=[1,2,3], then define b=a, now if I change a[0]=0, b[0] will change automatically as well. I tried this with objects, like the example above and a similar thing happened. I don't understand what is different about the implementation of this code, that left does not get set to None automatically.

Comment: "My understanding of python's mutable feature for classes/objects is that if you make an assignment then any change to the original changes the copy as well." - wrong. There is no copy. See http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @user6175310 with you example involving `test=root`, you're copying the object itself, so of course the `left` variable will be the same as the `left` variable from the same object, because they are literally the same variable.

Comment: @user2357112 sorry poor choice of words... but that was exactly the phenomenon I was trying to refer to... since there is no actual copy being made how come the left variable doesnt get set to None when root.left=None

Comment: @jphollowed but root.left is also a TreeNode object, so why is it that this same thing doesnt happen here?

Comment: `root.left = None` mutates the object referred to by `root`. The object referred to by `left`, which was referred to by `root.left` before the assignment, is unchanged.

Comment: @user6175310 Because this time you aren't copying the object instance, you're just copying the variable value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment in Python *always works the same way.* It changes the thing on the left side of the `=` sign to refer to the value of the expression on the right side. There is *absolutely nothing whatsoever* "different in the implementation" as you ask in a comment.

Sometimes the item on the left side is a slot in a container (a list, a dictionary, an object). These objects are mutable (able to be changed), so you can change what their slots refer to. When you do, for example:

```
a = b = [0]
```

Now `a` and `b` are two different names for the same object.  If you do `a[0] = 1` then `b[0]` also becomes 1, because `a` and `b` are the same object, and the assignment doesn't change this because you are assigning to slot 0 within the object referenced by `a`; you are not changing what `a` itself refers to. But if you instead do `a = [1]`, then `b[0]` remains 0, because `a` now points to a different list from `b`.

This is what's happening in your example. The names `left` and `root.left` initially refer to the same object.  When you change `root.left` to point to a different object, it doesn't change `left` to point to the same object. For that to happen, `left` would have to be a container, and it would have to be the same container as `root`, *not* `root.left`, and what would change would be `left.left`, not `left` itself. Because you can't change the value of a name by any way other than assigning to it.

Comment: Thank you! So basically if instead of assigning root.left to None, some change was made to the object (e.g. `root.left.left = None`, then this would change left ---> `left.left` would also become `None`) Is this correct?

Comment: Something like that. The rule of thumb is that you're only going to see a change to one object reflected in another object when the assignment is to a slot within an object (e.g. a list or dictionary item, or an object attribute), and only then if the other reference is to the same containing object (or a parent object, to be complete).

Comment: one other question, everytime in the while loop `current` gets assigned to `current.right` so at this point `root` and `current` are no longer pointing to the same tree object right? if this is the case, in the end `root` is returned. How does `root` keep getting updated? and however this is happening, why is it not equal to `current`, i.e. why is `current` not returned?

Comment: The function is recursive. After handling the root node, it calls itself to handle its left and right children. These function calls do the same with their children, and so on. `root` never gets updated in the initial function, but `root` is a different node in the recursive calls.